# Check type of variable before updating Database | PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function that updates a `user_token` for the respective `user_id`:

```
public function setUserToken($userId, $userToken)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE $this->dbname.user SET user_token=:user_token WHERE user_id=:user_id;");

        try {
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_token', $userToken, PDO::PARAM_STR, 70);
            $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', "sdf", PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result['success'] = $stmt->execute();
            $result['message'] = "Successfully updated user_token for user_id " . $userId;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $result['success'] = false;
            $result['message'] = "Failed to update user_token with error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

With this line:
`$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', "sdf", PDO::PARAM_INT);` and the `try-catch` operation, I have tried to throw an error if the `user_id` is not an integer.

But it fails. I guess it is because PHP automatically converts the "sdf" String to an integer with value 0.

What is the solution here?

Comment: Use function is_numeric to check whether the user_id is numeric and do the next operation

Comment: You say it fails because PHP converts the string "sdf" into an INT with value 0.  You are stating that the value for `:user_id` is to be an INT by using `PDO::PARAM_INT`  If user_id is the primary key for the table then most likely it will be an INT and therefor you will need to always pass it an INT not a string.  As Shibon states you can use `if( is_numeric( $userId ) ) { //Yes }` to check the variable before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. PDO doesn't enforce type casting with binding.  That is probably due to possible errors with precision - it is safer to send some value as string, to let a database sort the matters by itseslf.

In PHP7 you can declare a function argument with a hint to PHP, what type it have to be:

```
function whatever (int $id)
{
    echo $id;
}
whatever("sdf");
```

will throw an exception like you wanted.

If your PHP is outdated, then you have to write a code to check manually. For the particular function to use, you have to decide, whether you want to check the type of a variable or its content. For the former, you can use `is_int()` function, and `ctype_digit()` for the latter.

```
if (!ctype_digit($user_id))
{
     throw new Exception("Whatever");
}
```

Besides,

Note that your error handling is wrong. You shoudn't catch an error right in place, leaving the code as

```
public function setUserToken($userId, $userToken)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE $this->dbname.user SET user_token=:user_token WHERE user_id=:user_id;");

    $stmt->bindParam(':user_token', $userToken, PDO::PARAM_STR, 70);
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', "sdf", PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result['success'] = true;
    $result['message'] = "Successfully updated user_token for user_id " . $userId;
    return $result;
}
```

while error reporting have to centralized and safe, as described [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#json)

If you want to report validation errors back to the client, I don't see much point in it, but if you still want that, either return this error message directly from the validation code,

```
if (!ctype_digit($user_id))
{
     $result['success'] = false;
     $result['message'] = "wrong data type";
}
```

or create a distinct ValidationException, throw it, catch this one and send a report back to a client

Comment: Great answer. +1 for php7 reference and to get you closer to 111k!

Comment: Just to add to that, PHP will still do some type coercion for you when it won’t lose data. For example, if instead of 5 I used "5" for $userId, then PHP would automatically convert the String 5 to an integer 5.

This is fine in this particular question but just know that if you don't want automatic conversion you have to use strict typing, like this `declare(strict_types=1);` in the very first line of you script.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that